# How to simulate food items in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need to work on project which involves PR2 to pickup food items from a container[bowl] using a fork/spoon. But since we are very new to ROS/Gazebo, we are not sure about which type of food we can simulate on gazebo [i.e rice,fruit pieces,cereals etc].

Does anybody know of exiting food item models on gazebo or how difficult is it to create such models?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27606/how-to-simulate-food-items-in-gazebo/) by [shreeshga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1790/shreeshga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Give [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) a try. It's simple and easy to use. It can export to all ROS-support mesh types to be used in Gazebo. You won't be able to simulate the texture of foods (Gazebo bodies are rigid), but you can certainly create the shapes in no time at all.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shreeshga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1790/shreeshga/) on 2012-02-14**:
Thanks, guess will have to approximate food items to rigid shapes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @DimitriProsser said, simulating non-rigid bodies in Gazebo is tricky and not supported natively. An example of how such bodies can still be emulated by using particles can be seen in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0iRf4O1MOQ), but that is a special case that probably required quite some effort to realize.

Some rigid foot items like a milk carton and others are available in the [cob_gazebo_worlds](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_gazebo_worlds) package, in case you don't want to model them yourself. Spawned into the IPA kitchen environment, they look like in this image:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2